# How can i change whole background color when pop up box appears?

Tags: jquery

How can i change whole background color when pop up box appears?

I have got this code

```
    <img class="OtTTtFsDdAd" src="../img/L.png" title="Language" ID="SwWcSbDoTh">
    <div id="B">
<ul>
<li onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'"  id="OKASOKO">English</li>
<li onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" id="OKASOKO">Russian
</li></ul><a id="IANTCINSP">More languages are coming soon.</a>
</div>

$('#SwWcSbDoTh').on('click',function(){
$('#B').animate({opacity: 1,},1000);
$("body").css("opacity","0.25");
});
```

But when body opacity is 0.25 #B opacity is also 0.25

Comment: You can't, the `#B` element is inside the body, and will have the same opacity as the body. The solution for modern browsers would be to set the background with RGBA, and set the Alpha channel. Or, you can do what other popups do, use an overlay, an element overlaying everything with a grey/black partly visible background etc.

Comment: But other websites did it?For example Facebook

Comment: Not the way you're doing it, obviously !

Comment: @adeneo I know that.I am here to know how they are doing it)

Comment: are `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`  using instead of css hover?

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev What do you mean?

Comment: Google, facebook etc. are using an overlay, and element that is positioned fixed, covering the entire screen, that's partly visible, and then the popup is on top of that etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#SwWcSbDoTh').on('click',function(){
    $('#B').animate({opacity: 1,},1000, function(){
          //this will run after animation completed. 
          $("body").css("opacity","0.25");
    });
});
```

Comment: But isn't `#B` still inside the body, and will also have an opacity of `0.25` ? This doesn't change anything at all

Comment: Yes divs opacity becomes 0.25

Comment: for this you must create separated div in your html for all content and separated div for your modal and then set opacity for your container of all your content.

Comment: I have got div for all content in the beginning but it is also in body

Comment: if you have div for all content. the add modal to body and set the main div opacity

Comment: So i should change this line  $("body").css("opacity","0.25");

Comment: yes, think you main div have 'container' class. so your code will be  $(".container").css("opacity","0.25")

Comment: Now it is not even changing the opacity

Answer (score 0):

You can set background on animation complete callback something like this:

```
$('#SwWcSbDoTh').on('click',function(){
$('#B').animate({opacity: 1,complete:function(){
     $("body").css("opacity","0.25");}},1000);    
});
```

Comment: It is not even changing the opacity

Answer (score 0):

You just want a popup dialog with the other parts of the html window opaque, right?

Check out this example https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

~~~ Adding code sample

1) Refer these 3 files in your  tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

2) Prepare the content of the dialog in a div

```
<div id="dialog-message">
  <p>
    Modal dialog here
  </p>
</div>
```

3) Call function $().dialog to display the div

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
```

});

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good point. I see many answers here more than links. Added just now